# Redefine environment thebibliography

Tags: bibliographies, xetex, citing, environments

It was necessary to make a list of sources in the thesis. Different styles of `bibtex` and `biblatex` do not meet university standards (even GOST ones). Therefore, it was decided to arrange the list manually, using the `thebibliography` environment. But it doesn't display the list correctly.

The minimum code (only about 20 items, but I will leave only a few):

```
\begin{thebibliography}{99}
    \bibitem{Kotelnikov}
        \newblock {Котельников, И. А.} %1ый автор
        \newblock {LaTeX по-русски} : % название
        \newblock {учебник} / %жанр
        \newblock {И. А. Котельников, П. З. Чеботаев ; редактор Н. Р. Тевс}. -- %пишутся все авторы, редакторы, корректоры, переводчики, место написания (опционально) через точку с запятой
        \newblock {Санкт-Петербург} :%город издательства
        \newblock {Корона-Век}, % издательство
        \newblock {2016}. -- % год издания
        \newblock {496} с. : %кол-со страниц
        \newblock {ил.} -- %наличие иллюстраций, таблиц, цветных иллюстраций, портретов
        \newblock Библиогр.: С. {485-486}. -- %если в книге есть своя библиография (список источников), тогда нужно указать страницы. Если нет - удалить этот блок
        \newblock Текст : {непосредственный}.%возможен вариант ``электронный'', если издание копьютерное (на диске), но тогда нужно добавлять другие блоки до этого
        
    \bibitem{Lvovsky}
        \newblock {Львовский, С. М.} %1ый автор
        \newblock {Набор и вёрстка в системе \LaTeX} : % название
        \newblock {пособие} / %жанр
        \newblock {С.М. Львовский}. -- %пишутся все авторы, редакторы, корректоры, переводчики, место написания (опционально) через точку с запятой
        \newblock {5-e изд., переработанное}. --  %сведения об издании (опционально)
        \newblock {Москва} :%город издательства
        \newblock {МЦНМО}, % издательство
        \newblock {2014}. -- % год издания
        \newblock {400} с. : %кол-со страниц
        \newblock {ил.} -- %наличие иллюстраций, таблиц, цветных иллюстраций, портретов
        \newblock Библиогр.: С. {379-380}. -- %если в книге есть своя библиография (список источников), тогда нужно указать страницы. Если нет - удалить этот блок
        \newblock Текст : {непосредственный}.%возможен вариант ``электронный'', если издание компьютерное (на диске), но тогда нужно добавлять другие блоки до этого
        
    \bibitem{Pahomov}
        \newblock {Пахомов, Б.И.} %1ый автор
        \newblock {С\# для начинающих} : % название
        \newblock {руководство} / %жанр
        \newblock {Б.И. Пахомов ; группа подготовки издания: Е. Кондукова (главный редактор) [и др.]}. -- %пишутся все авторы, редакторы, корректоры, переводчики, место написания (опционально) через точку с запятой
        \newblock {Санкт-Петербург} : %город издательства
        \newblock {БХВ-Петербург}, % издательство
        \newblock {2014}. -- % год издания
        \newblock {432} с. : %кол-со страниц
        \newblock {ил.} -- %наличие иллюстраций, таблиц, цветных иллюстраций, портретов
        \newblock Текст : {непосредственный}.%возможен вариант ``электронный'', если издание компьютерное (на диске), но тогда нужно добавлять другие блоки до этого
        
    \bibitem{Baldin}
        \newblock {Балдин, Е. М.} %1ый автор
        \newblock {Компьютерная типография \LaTeX} : % название
        \newblock {руководство} / %жанр
        \newblock {E.М. Балдин}. -- %пишутся все авторы, редакторы, корректоры, переводчики, место написания (опционально) через точку с запятой
        \newblock {Новосибирск} :%город издательства
        \newblock опубликовано под лицензией {Creative Commons <<Атрибуция-СохранениеУсловий>> 3.0 Непортированная (CCBY-SA 3.0)}, % издательство
        \newblock {2013}. -- % год издания
        \newblock {308} с. : %кол-со страниц
        \newblock {ил.} -- %наличие иллюстраций, таблиц, цветных иллюстраций, портретов
        \newblock Библиогр.: с. {308}. -- %если в книге есть своя библиография (список источников), тогда нужно указать страницы. Если нет - удалить этот блок
        \newblock Систем. требования: Intel Pentium 1,6 GHz и более; 256 Мб (RAM) ; Microsoft Windows XP и выше ; Adobe Reader. -- 
        \newblock Текст : {электронный}.%возможен вариант ``электронный'', если издание компьютерное (на диске), но тогда нужно добавлять другие блоки до этого
        
    \bibitem{Pikabu}
        \newblock {LaTeX для новичков. Часть 2:Движки и преамбула} :%заголовок страницы
        \newblock {Пикабу} : сайт. --  %заголовок сайта
        \newblock {Франкфурт-на-Майне, Германия}. -- . --%расположение сервера сайта
        \newblock URL: {https://pikabu.ru/story/latex\_dlya\_novichkov\_chast\_2dvizhki\_i\_preambula\_5002998} %ссылка
        \newblock (дата обращения: {27.06.2021}). -- %дата обращения к сайту
        \newblock {Текст. Изображение} : электронные. %текст, опционально - иллюстрации, возможно даже видео.
        
    \bibitem{WikiSharp}
        \newblock {SharpDevelop} :%заголовок страницы
        \newblock {Википедия} : сайт. --  %заголовок сайта
        \newblock {Амстердам, Нидерланды}. -- . --%расположение сервера сайта
        \newblock URL: {https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/SharpDevelop} %ссылка
        \newblock (дата обращения: {10.09.2021}). -- %дата обращения к сайту
        \newblock {Текст. Изображение} : электронные. %текст, опционально - иллюстрации, возможно даже видео.
        
\end{thebibliography}
```

Now the list is displayed like this:
[image: Now]

As I understand it, the environment forms something like a table, where in one column there are numbers, and in the other - the record itself. Looks nice, but doesn't meet the required standard.

How to do:

[image: how to do]

I tried to redefine the `\bibitem` command, but I got only brackets instead of a dot after the number (which is already good). Means it is necessary to redefine all environment. It is important that the `\cite` command works, which is why I did not format the sources as a simple numbered list =)

I suppose that knowledge of plain TeX is needed here, that's why I ask for help, since I almost don't know it.

Distribution: TeXLive

Compiler: XeLaTeX

Comment: your problem is not related to the Plain TeX format, so I'm fixing the labels.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Almost six months after defending my own diploma, a solution was found. It is quite complex and non-obvious, besides, I did not fully understand it, but it works.

Taken from the source, which I will give below, but some values have been adjusted to display as close as possible to the one approved by normcontrol.

Source (description of the same problem, link to the final code can be found there): https://github.com/mstyura/bsuir-diploma-latex/issues/19

My solution is to add the following code to the preamble: (description of the same problem, link to the final code can be found there):

```
\usepackage[numbers]{natbib} %необходимый пакет для форматирования библиографии, опция добавляет номера

\setlength\bibindent{-1.09cm} %корректирует отступ каждого пункта (величина взята с источника)
\setlength{\bibsep}{0em} %убирает вертикальные интервалы между пунктами
%переопределение нумерации списка источников (круглая скобка)
\renewcommand{\@biblabel}[1]{\hspace{\parindent}#1)}

%для описания следующего кода мне не хватает опыта в LaTeX, но он взят из источника и работает
\renewcommand\NAT@bibsetnum[1]{\settowidth\labelwidth{\@biblabel{#1}}%
    \setlength{\leftmargin}{\bibindent}\addtolength{\leftmargin}{\dimexpr\labelwidth+\labelsep\relax}%
    \setlength{\itemindent}{-\bibindent+.4ex}% здесь корректировалась величина отступа, подгонялась под заголовок
    \setlength{\listparindent}{\itemindent}
    \setlength{\itemsep}{\bibsep}\setlength{\parsep}{\z@}%
    \ifNAT@openbib
    \addtolength{\leftmargin}{\bibindent}%
    \setlength{\itemindent}{-\bibindent}%
    \setlength{\listparindent}{\itemindent}%
    \setlength{\parsep}{10pt}%
    \fi
}
```

The result is the following:
[image: result of code]